# Unable to find 'java.nio.file.Files.walkFiletree'

Tags: android, gradle

I just updated my android studio to v2.0 and as soon as I did it I got running errors:

```
Unable to find method 'java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Ljava/nio/file/Path;Ljava/util/Set;ILjava/nio/file/FileVisitor;)Ljava/nio/file/Path;'
```

My `gradle-wrapper.properties` shows as:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Any solution?

By the way, the project was up and running until the update.

Comment: Are you on JDK v 1.8 as the install instructions indicate is required?

Comment: JDK v is 1.7.0.. So should i reinstall android studio? I have v1.41 as .exe

Comment: Voting to close the question, as it is no longer clear what error the poster is experiencing - it sounds like the JDK problem is fixed by updating to the version that the release notes say is required, and they've moved on to *unspecified* other errors in the xml code of their project itself, which is of course a difficult that can have no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per its installation instructions, Android Studio 2.0 requires JDK 1.8 / 8

Trying to run it on 1.7 is a likely suspect for your missing method and should be expected to cause other problems as well.

Comment: I downloaded & installed JDK 1.8.0_91. But i got some 103 errors of various xml and rest..

Comment: Vague mention of errors does not make a stack exchange site question.  Chances are however that you have various things in your code which trigger the stricter lint rules in the newer tool.  At any rate, those are distinct from the question asked in this posting.